# Difference between Measurable and $F$-measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we are given 2 measurable spaces, $(E,e),(F,f).$

A function $X:E\rightarrow F$ is called measurable (relative to $e$ and $f$) if $X^{-1}(q)\in e$ for all $q\in f$.

Now, I am studying joint-measurability of a function, and it discusses slices or sections of a function be $f$-measruable. What is the exact definition of a function being $f$-measurable instead of just being measurable, and what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

When $f$ is understood (for example, when it is the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$ we use the term 'measurable'. This is just $f$ measurability with a specific $f$ which is assumed to be known to us. So $f$ measurability is the general term and measurability is a special case.

Comment: I dont quite understand your response.